# Is "Suppose that 0' in V satisfies 0'+x=x for each x in V" the same as "Suppose there exists 0' in V such that 0'+x=x for each x in V".

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, self-learning

Do they have the same truth set?

When proving that 0 in V is unique

I choose a similar approach as the proof in [Corollary at page 554](https://i.stack.imgur.com/282pJ.jpg)

it starts with

> Suppose that 0' in V satisfies 0'+x=x for each x in V

then

0'+x=0+x

which ends with 0'=0 by cancelation law

My question is whether or not

> Suppose that 0' in V satisfies 0'+x=x for each x in V

is the same as

> Suppose that there exists 0' in V such that 0'+x=x for each x in V

?

====

I think I seem to begin realize the meaning of the proof.

> There does not exist $0'$ such that ($0'$+$x$=$x$ and $0'$=/=$0$)

is equivalent to

> For all $0'$, (if $0'$+$x$=$x$, then $0'$=$0$)

====

Comment: They aren't the same. The second one does not allow reference to the supposed other identity element 0' since in the second one, o' is universally quantified over. In a statement like "for all t G(t)" one may replace both t's by any other letter without changing the meaning, e.g. "for all u G(u)".

Comment: @coffeemath I don't quite understand that. Although I know that quantifiers has two kinds. Universal quantifier and existential quantifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely the same. In the first sentence, you are already taking for granted that $0'\in V$. Whereas in the second one, you are positing the existence of an element $0'\in V$.

However, the referenced proof is correct. The proof shows that if any element of $V$ satisfies the role of the additive identity, then that element is the identity itself. But the sentences are not the same as one already assumes such an element exists and the other posits the existence of such an element.

Comment: But the first one is adapted from a textbook.

Comment: @StatsCruncher After thinking about it some more, I have edited my answer. Have a look now.

Comment: I guess ... the second one is true only when the existence of 0'. On the contrary the first one is true whether 0' exists or not. Could I conclude that?

Comment: @StatsCruncher There are subtle differences with I don’t think you need to worry about. They are both correct.

Comment: I am still wondering. Ha. Maybe I will wait for some other answers.

Comment: Could you check it? I seem comprehend more deeply.

Comment: @StatsCruncher The second one  is true as we are positing the existence of $0’$. The first one is true because it shows that if any element of $V$ satisfies the conditions of an additive identity, then that element is the identity itself. Both prove the same thing and both are true. The only difference is in the assumptions.